# How can I ask a "community wiki" question such that the answerers can still earn reputation?

Tags: support, questions, answers, reputation, community-wiki

If I dont want to take the credit (reputation) for a question, but answerer should still obtain the reputation they deserve, is there some kind of a "question-only community wiki" option I can invoke?

The only thing which comes to my mind that would serve the purpose is disassociating the question from my account after asking, but I have heard that people are not very fond of doing this without stringent reasons ...

Comment: I am really a bit puzzled about what is there to "disagree" with a question asking for support ... ;-)?

Comment: *My dear* Dilaton, only because this question is so *ridiculous*. Why should the answerer gain rep? If the he is greedy for rep, he won't answer the question at all..! And IMHO, our site doesn't have (or has very less) users concerning rep, because most of us here. And, I really wanna say that most of us here are *hopefully* mature physicists who just answer questions and ***don't concern rep*** ;-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy why should the answeres not gain rep for a good answer ;-). If I think I should not gain rep for a question, this does not mean that people who nicely answer is should not be able to obtain it either. I am not concerned about my rep (this is why I say I dont want to take the rep for my question), but I am concerned about the answerers who deserve rep for nice posts? Good for you if you find this issue ridiculous ;-), but I mean it quite honest and seriously. Cheers

Comment: @CrazyBuddy I did not say that I think I will get no answers, if I make the question CW by the way, I dont ...

Comment: I don't think you got me right. *"If I think I should not gain rep for a question"* I can't quite get a grip why do you think so? If you give somewhat higher preference to answers than your questions, I'd suggest you don't use CW for questions..! ;-)

Comment: [meta-math] could do it:   http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Why would you want this though?

Either way, question-only CW will not be used for this. (For that matter, try not to use answer CW for this either, but it's not that bad a thing if you do)

Comment: I need this when I feel it would be some kind of dishonest to take the rep for the question, but he answerers should still obtain it. It would be nice if in the same way, one can make an anser CW without effecting the question (and other answers), one could make a question "CW" without affection all future answers.

Comment: @Dilaton that's not the point of CW.

Comment: Is there some work around how I can achieve the effect I want?

Comment: @Dilaton Nope, not really

Comment: This answer is incorrect. [How much water must flow trough canal to maintain a constant water deep?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30052)

Answer (score 1):

I see that it is possible,.

If your question is community wiki because you've edited it at least 10 times, or because at least 5 different people have edited it (as opposed to a moderator making it community wiki), then the answers **do not automatically** become Community Wiki.

c.f.            [How much water must flow trough canal to maintain a constant water deep?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30052/how-much-water-must-flow-trough-canal-to-maintain-a-constant-water-deep)